# "Associate app to the store" option does not show on VS 2012

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I developed a Windows Phone 8 App. But when I try to add it to the store the option "Associate app to the store" does not show (could not post pics because i´m new here).

The options does not appear when I right click on the project AND it also does not work when I click on the Visual Studio 2012 menu PROJECT > STORE > (the option to associate the app shows as disabled)

Also I tried to add the  tag manually on my WMAppManifest.xml file with no avail either. In this particular case, the app wont start in the emulator. It keeps on loading forever.

The current status to my developer account is "need verification" - meaning: I need to wait to the credit card transaction to pop out on my bank to input the secret code. Is that the case? Is that why I cant associate the app and why it does not show on Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: If you've got links to your picture(s) on a public site, just include the info in the post - a more highly privileged user will edit the post to show the pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That menu is only meant for Windows 8 apps, not Windows Phone 8 apps. You should use http://dev.windowsphone.com for all your windows phone store activities. Again, VS2012 doesn't have any built-in integration with the WP8 store, just the Win8 store.

Comment: You are right. Seems I need another $99 to get a windows phone developer account... geeeeez

Comment: u just put off me of my two days misery